# Javascript window.close() popup issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, popupwindow

In one of my application, I am opening popup through JavaScript ***window.open()*** and if user opens the same link; I want to close that previously open popup through ***window.close()***.

Now for below mentioned cases IE doesn;t able to close previously open popup and it is opening multiple.

> 1) **Internal Link:**
>   For Internal links that means opening different pages of the same application in Popup it is working fine for all the browser.
>
> 2) **External Link:** If I open external link to 3<sup>rd</sup> party application OR any other external page like Google.com or so this functionality is working for all other browser except IE(Internal Explorer).

Is there any solution to this ?....

Any JavaScript code that will help you to achieve the same functionality cross browser platform ?....

Any sample would be appreciated.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a window name as a second argument to window.open(). If a window with that name is already open, it will be reused.

```
window.open(myUrl, 'myPopupWinodw');
```

If you use the same window name, you don't need to close the previous popup, as the url will be opened in the same popup window.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: I am using the __popupWindowName__ ; However it doesn't work for IE. For other browser it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you

```
function closeWindow() {
 var Browser = navigator.appName;
 var indexB = Browser.indexOf('Explorer');

 if (indexB > 0) {
    var indexV = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') + 5;
    var Version = navigator.userAgent.substring(indexV, indexV + 1);

    if (Version >= 7) {
        window.open('', '_self', '');
        window.close();
    }
    else if (Version == 6) {
        window.opener = null;
        window.close();
    }
    else {
        window.opener = '';
        window.close();
    }    
 }
else { window.close(); }        

}
```